# Task email template with name of associated contact, not ID

Tags: email-template, tasks

I have what seems to be a very simple problem, I'm trying to set up an email template with information from a task. One of the fields I would like to include is the name of the associated contact or "Name" field, which shows up as WhoId but only shows the contact ID.

I have tried using a workflow and the process builder to update a custom field to contain the name of the contact but that doesn't work either. I would appreciate any ideas that I could try. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do this. You'll need a VF email template

**Email template**

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Task Polymorphic" recipientType="Contact"
                         relatedToType="Task">
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >

some blah blah markup and merge fields     

Associated name: <c:TaskPolymorphicDisplay whoId="{!relatedTo.whoId}"></c:TaskPolymorphicDisplay>

more blah blah markup and merge fields     

</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

**VF custom component TaskPolymorphicDisplay**

```
<apex:component controller="TaskPolymorphicFetchController" access="global">
    <apex:attribute name="whoId" assignTo="{!taskWhoId}" type="id"  description="task whoID" />
    <apex:outputText value="{!name}"/>
</apex:component>
```

**VF Custom controller for the component**

```
public class TaskPolymorphicFetchController {

    public ID taskWhoId {get; set;}
    public String getName() {
        if (String.isBlank(this.taskWhoId)) 
            return null;
        else
        if (this.taskWhoId.getSobjectType() == Contact.SObjectType)
            return [select name from Contact where id = :taskWhoId limit 1].name;
        else
        if (this.taskWhoId.getSobjectType() == Lead.SobjectType)
            return [select name from Lead where id = :taskWhoId limit 1].name;
        else
        if (this.taskWhoId.getSobjectType() == User.SobjectType)
            return [select name from User where id = :taskWhoId limit 1].name;
        else 
            return null;
    }
}
```

**How does this work?**

The VF email template relatedToType is a Task. You insert a VF custom component that in turn will take the whoId attribute value, assign to the custom controller `taskWhoId` property via the action of the setter.

Then after the setter(s) have run, the component is rendered by calling the getter on `{!name}` that is attached to a `getName()` method in the controller.

`getName()` looks at the sobjectType of the whoId and does the appropriate SOQL

When the email is rendered in the testing window for a task that is a child of Contact `Freddie Fubar`, I get this:

```
Associated name:Freddie Fubar
```

**Disclaimers**

I threw this together and the controller could be a whole lot more generalized to also accept another argument `fieldName` and then return the requested field name rather than being hardcoded to just the name field on the whoId sobjecttype choices

If using shared activities, the problem is more complex as one task can have many whoIds. Exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're trying to overcome is that the `WhoId` is a [polymorphic field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_polymorph_keys.htm). It could just as easily be a reference to a `Lead` as it could a `Contact`. Unless you have a means of specifying in your template that the `TypeOf(Who) = Contact`, you won't be able to use `Who.Name` in your template.

I'm not aware of any visualforce that provides the kind of functionality to allow you to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can put `{!Contact.Name}` in the template.

As long as the task is associated with a Contact this will populate correctly. Other fields such as `{!Contact.Link}` also work.